# Como inserir uma data específica no Calendar do Swift3?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift-3

Preciso inserir uma data específica no Calendar, porém só estou conseguindo somar valores com base na data atual (talvez porque quando instancio, dou uma Calendar.current). Alguém sabe como inserir (dia, mês e ano) separadamente?

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você precisa dos componentes separados utilizando [`DateComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/datecomponents):

```
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.year = 2017
dateComponents.month = 5
dateComponents.day = 20
```

Daí então você pode definir uma data com base nestes componentes:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let date = calendar.date(from: dateComponents)
```

Além do ano, mês e dia, existem também outros componentes que podem ser definidos.